# Make WordPress size and name images for Retina.js

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, content

I'm a huge fan of the way [retina.js](http://retinajs.com/) works for high pixel density displays. Essentially, when it's loading image assets (via `<img>` or css image) it will check if there's a `@2x` suffix version of the image (eg. if there's a `logo.jpg` it will automatically show the `logo@2x.jpg` in its place if it exists.

The WordPress function `the_post_thumbnail` lets me define various image sizes, but I want to know if there's a way to have it also create versions of the images that are twice the size with the `@2x` suffix as well!

It's easy to do this for theme files, but would be pretty awesome to allow this for content images as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Wordpress plugin

[Wp Retina 2X](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/screenshots/)

Comment: I'm hoping to do this without a plugin - but this is the place to start! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my advice.

Just create the copies of images with double size using wordpress native media settings. And then add the following code in your templates.

```
<?php $normal = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail');
$retina = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $normal[0]; ?>" data-at2x="<?php echo $retina[0]; ?> alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="xxx" height="xxx"/>
```

Here my thumbnail (normal) size is 300x300px and medium thumbnail (retina) has 600x600px size. And also don't forget to load retina.js otherwise **data-at2x=** will not work. Good luck!