# Retina for Wordpress Posts

Tags: posts, genesis-theme-framework, retina

I was [checking one of the answers here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114091), and it says:

> Just create the copies of images with double size using wordpress
>   native media settings. And then add the following code in your
>   templates.

```
<?php $normal = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail');
$retina = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' ); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $normal[0]; ?>" data-at2x="<?php echo $retina[0]; ?> alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="xxx" height="xxx"/>
```

> Here my thumbnail (normal) size is 300x300px and medium thumbnail
>   (retina) has 600x600px size. And also don't forget to load retina.js
>   otherwise data-at2x= will not work. Good luck!"

--

I'm using the Genesis Framework, and I'm wondering where you'd suggest adding the above code

Comment: Who are you talking too? Please format your questions and read the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Please check the post and more or less it seems you have put a new questions whereas you wanted to reply in an other thread :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make WordPress size and name images for Retina.js](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100255/make-wordpress-size-and-name-images-for-retina-js)

Comment: @MarutiMohanty, new users can only comment in other people's Q or A's after 50rep. John, ask a Question when you have a problem with code *you are writing*. The answer is in the first sentence you quoted: ***"add the following code in your templates"***, theme templates that is (the one that is appropriate for you).